# Bind to service not working

Tags: android, android-activity, service, binding

I have a service that I intend to use from an activity. However when i run my program the my variable `isBound`, which I use to invoke `RunOnUIThread()` to update my UI does not change from `false` to `true`. The program had implemented the necessary methods for the binding process but seems that some are not invoked.

Here is the code for my activity:

```
namespace Oasis

public class DemoActivity : Activity
{
    bool isBound = false;
    bool isConfigurationChange = false;
    DemoServiceBinder binder;
    DemoServiceConnection demoServiceConnection;

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);


        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.DemoServiceUI);

        var start = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.startService);

        start.Click += delegate
        {
            StartService (new Intent (this, typeof(DemoService)));
        };

        var stop = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.stopService);
        stop.Click += delegate
        {
            StopService (new Intent (this, typeof(DemoService)));
        };

        var callService = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.callService);

        callService.Click += delegate
        {
            if (isBound)
            {
                RunOnUiThread(() =>
                {
                    string text = binder.GetDemoService().GetText();

                    if (text == "Foo")
                    {
                    UpdateUI();
                    }

                }
                );
            }
        };

        var btnnext = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.nextlayout);
        btnnext.Click += btnnext_Click;

        demoServiceConnection = LastNonConfigurationInstance as DemoServiceConnection;

        if (demoServiceConnection != null)
            binder = demoServiceConnection.Binder;
    }


    void btnnext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var intent = new Intent(this, typeof(DatabaseFormActivity));
        StartActivity(intent);
    }

    protected override void OnStart()
    {
        base.OnStart();

        var demoServiceIntent = new Intent("DemoService");
        demoServiceConnection = new DemoServiceConnection(this);
        BindService(demoServiceIntent, demoServiceConnection, Bind.AutoCreate);

    }

    protected override void OnDestroy()
    {
        base.OnDestroy();

        if (!isConfigurationChange)
        {
                if (isBound)
                {
                    UnbindService(demoServiceConnection);
                    isBound = false;
                }

        }
    }


    public override Java.Lang.Object OnRetainNonConfigurationInstance()
    {
        base.OnRetainNonConfigurationInstance();

        isConfigurationChange = true;

        return demoServiceConnection;
    }

    class DemoServiceConnection : Java.Lang.Object, IServiceConnection
    {
        DemoActivity activity;
        DemoServiceBinder binder;

        public DemoServiceBinder Binder
        {
            get
            {
                return binder;
            }
        }

        public DemoServiceConnection(DemoActivity activity)
        {
            this.activity = activity;
        }

        public void OnServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service)
        {
            var demoServiceBinder = service as DemoServiceBinder;
            if (demoServiceBinder != null)
            {
                var binder = (DemoServiceBinder)service;
                activity.binder = binder;
                activity.isBound = true;

                this.binder = (DemoServiceBinder)service;
            }
        }

        public void OnServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name)
        {
            activity.isBound = false;
        }
    }
}
```

And the code for the Service:

```
[Service]
[IntentFilter(new String[]{"DemoService"})]
public class DemoService : Service
{
DemoServiceBinder binder;
        private static System.Timers.Timer aTimer;


    public override StartCommandResult OnStartCommand (Android.Content.Intent intent, StartCommandFlags flags, int startId)
    {
        Log.Debug ("DemoService", "DemoService started");

        StartServiceInForeground ();

        DoThis ();

        return StartCommandResult.NotSticky;
    }

    void StartServiceInForeground ()
    {
        var ongoing = new Notification (Resource.Drawable.Icon, "DemoService in foreground");
        var pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetActivity (this, 0, new Intent (this, typeof(DemoActivity)), 0);
        ongoing.SetLatestEventInfo (this, "DemoService", "DemoService is running in the foreground", pendingIntent);

        StartForeground ((int)NotificationFlags.ForegroundService, ongoing);
    }

    public override void OnDestroy ()
    {
        base.OnDestroy ();

                    aTimer.Stop();
                aTimer.Dispose();
    }

    void SendNotification ()
    {
        var nMgr = (NotificationManager)GetSystemService (NotificationService);
        var notification = new Notification (Resource.Drawable.Icon, "Message from demo service");
        var pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetActivity (this, 0, new Intent (this, typeof(DemoActivity)), 0);
        notification.SetLatestEventInfo (this, "Demo Service Notification", "Message from demo service", pendingIntent);
        nMgr.Notify (0, notification);
    }

    public void DoThis()
    {
                    Intent demoServiceIntent = new Intent("DemoService");
        Toast.MakeText (this, "The demo service has started", ToastLength.Long).Show ();
                    Log.Debug("DemoService", "DoWork() started");
                    //SetTimer();
        var t = new Thread (() => {

            SendNotification ();
                    SetTimer();
                        Log.Debug("DemoService", "Timer is set");

        }
        );

    }

    public override Android.OS.IBinder OnBind (Android.Content.Intent intent)
    {
        binder = new DemoServiceBinder (this);
        return binder;
            }

    public string GetText ()
    {
                    string message = Verification.GetResponseMessage();

                if (message !="")
                {
                    KillTimer();

                }
                    return message;
    }

            private static void KillTimer()
            {
                aTimer.Stop();

            }

            private static void SetTimer()
            {
                    aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(10000);
                 aTimer.Elapsed += OnTimedEvent;
                    aTimer.AutoReset = true;
                    aTimer.Enabled = true;

            }

            private static void OnTimedEvent(Object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
            {

                    Verification.Verify();


            }

}

public class DemoServiceBinder : Binder
{
    DemoService service;

    public DemoServiceBinder (DemoService service)
    {
        this.service = service;
    }

    public DemoService GetDemoService ()
    {
        return service;
    }
}

    public class Verification
    {
    public string Verify(){
            static string responsemessage;
    }
        }

        public static string GetResponseMessage()
        {


            if (responsemessage != null)
            {
            return responsemessage;

            }
        else
            {
            return "";
            }

    }

}
```

}

Comment: add some `Log.d` inside `OnStart`, `OnBind` etc, what does `BindService` return ?

Comment: Thank you. Its working now, I think it got something to do with not being able to register the service in the andrioidmanifest.